# Sql query for matching multiple values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

dfsdfi have these tables

### product

```
product_id      name
51                a
52                 b
53                 c
54                 s
55                 e
```

### product_filter

```
product_id      filter_id
52                 11
53                 22
54                 33
52                 22
54                 11
```

### filter_group_description

```
filter_group_id     filter_id        name
1                     11             white  
1                     22             black
2                     33             formals
2                     44             casuals
```

### filter_group

```
filter_group_id      name
1                   Colour
2                   Style
```

What i want here is product name where colour is black and white but style should be formals..

Comment: Your query makes no sense whatsoever.  It should be returning a syntax error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: basically i want product_id where filter_id in (filter_ids) grouped by filter_group_id

Comment: suppose i have 2 filter groups 1. Colour 2. Style 

and i have filters like black, grey, white, formal, casual

if i use In operator like filter_id in(8,5,4) it gives all the products but all i want filter_id of different group shall be like in(8,5) AND in (6,4)

Comment: @MohsinShaikh . . . The explanation and desired results should be in the question, not a comment.  Please edit the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is the question clear now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_filter p 
INNER JOIN filter_group f ON f.filter_id = p.filter_id 
WHERE p.filter_id IN (11,22,33,44)
```

If you just want to get back some columns, change the `*`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.filter_id, f.filter_group_id
FROM `product_filter` p
JOIN `filter_group` f
ON p.filter_id = f.filter_id
```